# Is Reddit Oauth page not responsive?

Tags: ios, oauth, responsive-design, oauth-2.0, reddit

I'm trying to integrate Reddit API into my iOS app. So far I've managed to work through the entire back-and-forth dance and authentication. Basically it's functional.

However I am a bit put off by the authorization page where users have to sign in and authorize access which looks like this:

[image]

However on my iPhone this page is rendered as if it would be rendered on a desktop and I have to zoom in to view and even click on these tiny buttons. I was wondering if this is because of how I implemented it, or if everyone gets the same non-responsive page.

BTW I'm using SFSafariViewController to open the webpage.

Comment: I believe that if you use `i.reddit.com` rather than `reddit.com` (or add `.compact` to the page), you'll get a more mobile-friendly page.  However, I can't test right now.

Comment: Thanks, i.reddit.com worked....kind of. I do indeed see a responsive website but it's super sketchy and has a design of fake iOS UI from like 10 years ago. I guess they attempted to make it look like you're viewing a native app. I hope they have another option.